# Automatically convert csv file into Excel table?

Tags: excel, csv

I generate some csv files using a script. Next I manually convert those csv files into excel tables using the import wizard in excel based on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5Pxil4jVO4

Is it possible to do this automatically - e.g. by calling an excel importer from command line - so I don't need to open excel and do all the manual work?

I can open the csv file directly in Excel but its not formatted as a table. E.g. this csv file:

```
a,b,c
a,b,c
```

results in this Excel sheet:

[image]

I would like each letter to be in a separate column.

I have looked at this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/370ee470-f2cd-4f30-a167-b106dd51d47a/powershell-convert-csv-to-xlsx?forum=winserverpowershell

but its an awful lot of boiler plate code from create a simple table.

Comment: It is possible to link the csv extension to Excel directly and just open the csv files in Excel. Excel will then try to execute the converter by itself (if it does not succeed it will display all the rows in te csv file as separate rows in the sheet, but they can of course be converted) Success depends on whether Excel is able to interpret the csv file correctly. Things like list separators and textindicators are important. Is an Excel file the final result that you need? You may be able to script to Excel directly.

Comment: Are you familiar with Python? You could then write a script that reads csv files and writes xlsx files directly.

Comment: Data ► Get External Data ► From Text ► Delimited ► Comma ► Finish. It seems that your computer's system regional settings do not use a comma as the standard list separator.

Comment: Hm and how do I change that so I don't have to change it in excel each time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add an extra line to your CSV file to tell Excel what the seperator is. Add the following line to the top of your CSV file:

`sep=,`

Comment: Excellent and simple

Comment: This right here is the top solution. Easy to add for the developer, no extra effort for the user dealing with the CSV in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, without close and edit your file - you can choose which separator you want in Excel 2010-2016 go to DATA, Text To Columns, choose Delimited, then choose your separator Comma (or other) and you will see changes immediately in the "Data preview", then click FInish.
Once you have the format you wanted, you simply save the document and it will be permanent.